# Wordpress colorpicker save both hex and RGB

Tags: custom-field, jquery, admin, color-picker

Trying to get both the hex and RGB value of a color from the native color picker in Wordpress, user chooses the color via a custom metabox in the admin. Just need to save both values as meta for re-use in the interface.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.color-field').wpColorPicker();
});
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. TXS.

Comment: You can get the RGB value via the `change` event: `change: function ( event, ui ) { var rgb = ui.color.toCSS( 'rgb' ); ... }` - see the "Advanced usage" section [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/11/30/new-color-picker-in-wp-3-5/) and the Color.js [docs](https://github.com/Automattic/Color.js/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Sally, here is the completed jQuery which pushes the RGB value to another field. Name of the RGB field has `_rgb` at the end.

```js
jQuery(function() {
    var myOptions = {
        // you can declare a default color here,
        // or in the data-default-color attribute on the input
        defaultColor: false,
        // a callback to fire whenever the color changes to a valid color
        change: function(event, ui){
            var rgb = ui.color.toCSS( 'rgb' );
            var name = jQuery(this).attr("name");
            name = '#' + name + '_rgb';
            jQuery(name).val(rgb);
        },
        // a callback to fire when the input is emptied or an invalid color
        clear: function() {},
        // hide the color picker controls on load
        hide: true,
        // show a group of common colors beneath the square
        // or, supply an array of colors to customize further
        palettes: true
    };
    jQuery('.color-field-custom').wpColorPicker(myOptions);
});
```

And here is what the custom field looks like below the color picker field.

```php
<input type="text" name="destination_secondary_color_rgb" id="destination_secondary_color_rgb" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'destination_secondary_color_rgb', true); ?>" />
```

Comment: PS: You should escape dynamic values, and for `input` fields, you can use [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) - e.g. `<input name="foo" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option( 'foo' ) ); ?>">` :)